# (n) documents DTD into an Xhtml document + pass validator W3c?

Tags: xhtml

I need yes or yes XHTML 1.1 strict, no html5.

That is the code of my **doc.xhtml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "prueba.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Galaxy</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</head><body><div>
<nav>
<esphere>
<planet>Jupiter!</planet>
</esphere>
</nav>
</div>
</body></html>
```

That is the code of my **DTD**:

```
<!ENTITY % InlPhras.class "| esphere | nav | planet ">
<!ELEMENT esphere ANY>
<!ELEMENT nav ANY>
<!ELEMENT planet ANY>
<!ENTITY % html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
%html;
```

The combination of this two files, (the two codes together) run fine in validator W3C, but really this is a correct method to add elements to XHTML 1.1 strict?

How I can define best the element planet?
(by example weight, radio, gravity...)

Aditionally, if I begin the page without DIV element, then validator fail.
Why?
Why is a requeriment begin the document XHTML with DIV ?

Comment: [InlPhras.class](https://ddialliance.org/Specification/DDI-Codebook/2.5/XMLSchema/field_level_documentation_files/schemas/ddi-xhtml11-model-1_xsd/groups/InlPhras.class.html) is for phrase elements. In XHTML 1.1 Strict, the content model for body elements doesn't permit phrase elements. So you need an element in between that is both permitted as a child of body and permits phrase elements as its children. The div element does that. The remainder of your question is unclear what you're asking, but it looks to be seeking an opinion, so it's probably off-topic.

Comment: Thakns @Alohci, the "remainder of my Q" is about: ok, my code is GREEN in "validator" but is correct technically?, or OTHER method is is best to ADD DTD from W3C + MYDTD ???